# Code that will draw a rectangle using # prints in single block

Tags: java

My professor ask me to:

> Create a code in java that will reads the length and the width of rectangle. Drawing of a rectangle with the given dimensions would be drawn using the character "#" . the program should continuously read pairs of numbers.

(first length, then width) and outputs the calculated QPI after the end of  input is met.

> Input:
>
> The input file will consist of a series of pairs of integers separated by a  space; one pair of integers per line.  The first number in each pair is the  rectangle's length while the other one is the width.
>
> Output:
>
> Each rectangle (with the inputted dimensions) is ouputted using the character '#'.

There should be an empty space after each drawing.

Sample Input:

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
```

Sample Output:

```
#

##
##

###
###
###
```

This is the code that I create but only 1 set of numbers is only input

```
import java.io.*;

public class ActivityThree {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
    BufferedReader dataIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String input = "";
    String output = "";
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int inputParse = 0;
    int outputParse = 0;
    try{
        System.out.print("Enter Length: ");
        input = dataIn.readLine();
        System.out.print("Enter Width: ");
        output = dataIn.readLine();
    }catch( IOException e ){
        System.out.println("Error!");
    }
    inputParse = Integer.parseInt(input);
    outputParse = Integer.parseInt(output);

    for(a = inputParse; a > 0; a--) {
        for(b=0; b < outputParse; b++) {
            if(a >= inputParse)
                System.out.print("#");
            else
                System.out.print("#");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: -1, `my professor ask me to...` - Ok, then maybe you should write the code. We don't mind helping if you have a specific question, but we are not going to do your homework for you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It is not constructive to just post an assignment and ask for a solution. StackOverflow is designed for help learning your profession, not doing your work. What approaches have you tried with this? What problems have you encountered?

Comment: i posted the code that I made.....sorry

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Luigi: nothing happened. the i want to know how can i make my inputs many like 5 pairs of integer. then the output is also 5 rectangles of #..

Comment: @AbbyDominguez yes, I misunderstood the problem. I've updated my answer.

Comment: but how?TT^TT sorry.i'm having a hard with loops...TT^TT

Comment: So the question is essentially how to make the program able to loop?

Comment: yes.. how about this one : for(a=0; a<=5; a++); i'll put it before "catch" is that right?

Comment: Here's something that might help: put the logic that actually prints the result (which is the loop you already have) in a separate function. (Hopefully, you've learned about functions.) Then you just need to create a loop that calls your function several times.

Comment: @AbbyDominguez The `for` loop you wrote will allow you to enter 5 different "rectangles" before leaving the loop. Now all that's left is to add the code inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

> This is the code that I create but only 1 set of numbers is only input

Indeed your code prints a rectangle using `#` as expected. You just need to use a *loop* structure to make this work many times. There are three *loop* structures to accomplish this:

- `while`
- `do-while`
- `for`

It's up to you to decide which one to use (not showing more since this is an exercise). More info:

- [The `while` and `do-while` Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)
- [The `for` Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

---

By the way, you're already using a `for` loop in your solution to control how many times you need to write a character in a line. You can use another of these statements for a bigger block of code. Just identify the block of code that you need to *repeat* an amount of times, probably since the user input (hint: `System.out.print("Enter Length: ");`).

Comment: Something the OP will need to address is how to stop the loop as well. The input we see doesn't suggest whether to expect a blank line or end of file or what have you. OP might want to talk to the professor about what the stop condition is.

Comment: @jpmc26 by reading the problem, looks like this should be an infinite loop or probably the problem is wrong stated. Anyway, there are more problems in OP's code like never closing the `BufferedReader dataIn`, but that's unrelated to the concrete problem.

Comment: No, there is some kind of stop condition. "Output the calculated QPI after the end of input." I'm not sure what the QPI is, but that obviously can't happen without a stop condition. Ctrl+C wouldn't allow for it.

Comment: @jpmc26 then the problem is wrongly stated. The teacher, professor or whoever is teaching Java to OP must update the problem statement to clearer this (not us).

Comment: That's what I said: "OP might want to talk to the professor about what the stop condition is." =)

Comment: @jpmc26 sorry, I re-read your first comment after reading your last one and now understand what you mean. I must get some sleep by this time =\