# A code that will draw a rectangle in java part2

Tags: java, loops, drawing

our prof made a revise about the problem:

Draw me a Rectangle!

Filename: ActivityThree.java

Input file:  activitythree.in

Maritess is starting to appreciate ASCII art.  She ventured to start writing a program that reads the length and width of a rectangle.  An ASCII drawing of a rectangle with the given dimensions would then be "drawn" using the ASCII character '#'. The program should continuously read pairs of numbers

(first length, then width) and outputs the calculated QPI after the end of  input is met.

Input:

The input file will consist of a series of pairs of integers separated by a  space; one pair of integers per line.  The first number in each pair is the  rectangle's length while the other one is the width.

Output:

Each rectangle (with the inputted dimensions) is ouputted using the character '#'.

There should be an empty space after each drawing.

Sample Input:

```
1 1

2 2

3 3

5 6

9 10
```

Sample Output:

```
#
--------


##

##

-------------- 

###

###

###

------------- 

#####

#####

#####

#####

#####

#####

 ----------------------

#########

#########

#########

#########

#########

#########

#########

#########

#########

#########
```

this is still may code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class ActivityThree {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

    BufferedReader dataIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String input = "";
    String output = "";
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int inputParse = 0;
    int outputParse = 0;
    try{
    System.out.print("Enter Length: ");
    input = dataIn.readLine();
    System.out.print("Enter Width: ");
    output = dataIn.readLine();
    }catch( IOException e ){
    System.out.println("Error!");
    }
    inputParse = Integer.parseInt(input);
    outputParse = Integer.parseInt(output);

    for(a = inputParse; a > 0; a--){
        for(b=0; b < outputParse; b++){
        if(a >= inputParse)
            System.out.print("#");
         else
            System.out.print("#");
                        }
        System.out.print("\n");
                        }
}
}
```

thank you so much,.

Comment: This question will be closed as duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/17646224/1065197 in 3, 2, 1...

Comment: By the way, I've updated my answer to show where you can start a loop in your code. If you're looking for somebody that will do this for you, then you're in the wrong site.

Comment: you don't need if else inside loop and put the `System.out.print("\n");` outside of inner loop

Comment: @JigarJoshi the `System.out.print("\n")` is outside the inner `for` loop, just that OP doesn't use braces for the `if-else`.

Comment: if(a >= inputParse) and else are doing the same thing. ?

Answer (score 0):

While I don't really approve of posting the full code like this, it seems useful in this case for explaining how to do what you're looking for piece by piece. Please read the comments and attempt to understand what is going on rather than simply copying and pasting to get your homework done. And of course, if you have any specific questions, feel free to ask.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ActivityThree {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        // most of the code here for reading from a file I borrowed from
        // http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/

        BufferedReader br = null;
        int length, width;

        try {

            String currentLine;

            // open the file and start reading it
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("activitythree.in"));
            currentLine = br.readLine();

            // only need to do anything if there is something in the file
            if (currentLine != null) {

                // using a do-while loop instead of a while loop so that
                // we can check if there is another line and print out a
                // blank line before the next rectangle
                do {

                    // split the line into two strings, length and width
                    String[] dimensions = currentLine.split(" ");

                    // parse the strings into integers
                    // if they are not proper numbers, set them to 0
                    try {
                        length = Integer.parseInt(dimensions[0]);
                        width = Integer.parseInt(dimensions[1]);
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        length = 0;
                        width = 0;
                    }

                    // print out the rectangle
                    printRectangle(length, width);

                    // read the next line and print out a 
                    // blank line if there was something to read
                    currentLine = br.readLine();
                    if (currentLine != null) {
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                } while (currentLine != null);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            // you should always close a file when you're done with it
            try {
                if (br != null) {
                    br.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void printRectangle(int length, int width) {

        // make sure we're trying to print a rectangle with real dimensions
        if (length <= 0 || width <= 0) {
            return;
        }

        // print `length` lines
        for (int l = 0; l < length; l++) {

            // print `width` #'s in each line
            for (int w = 0; w < width; w++) {

                // using print() because the #'s need to all be on one line
                System.out.print("#");
            }

            // print out a newline when we're done printing  #'s
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

This input file:

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
5 6
9 10
```

produces this output:

```
#

##
##

###
###
###

######
######
######
######
######

##########
##########
##########
##########
##########
##########
##########
##########
##########
```